# How to let script on Cloudflare Workers running in localhost

Tags: node.js, web-worker, httpserver, cloudflare-workers

I installed nodejs on my computer, and I want to run cloudflare workers scripts on localhost or VPS. It seems like use Web Worker API to pass request.

How can I set up my nodejs environment？

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Miniflare to run a Cloudflare Worker locally for testing: https://miniflare.dev/

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [wrangler2](https://github.com/cloudflare/wrangler2).

Easy setup, no configuration needed and miniflare is already included.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).